# SQL Subquery to replace all values

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, subquery, sql-server-2016

I have a query which returns a bunch of different data, however I want to have it replace all the values upon a certain condition.

What I have written below kind of gives me the result I want but not really. It creates a new column instead of replacing the other one:
[image]

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN T4.[U_DestType] = '6'
            THEN (SELECT
              'Company Limited' AS [ShipToCode]
              )
    END AS [ShipToCode],
    T2.[ShipToCode],
    T6.[StreetS],
    T6.[StreetNoS],
    T6.[CityS],
    T6.[ZipCodeS],
    T6.[CountryS],
    T5.[LicTradNum],
    T2.[CardCode],
    T4.[Phone1],
    T4.[E_Mail],
    T4.[U_DestType],
    CASE
        WHEN T4.[Country] = 'GB'
            THEN 'EN'
        ELSE T4.[Country]
    END AS [Country],
    T4.[U_ShortName]
FROM[...]
```

The end goal is to replace all of the columns with some preset values instead of just ShipToCode as above.

I tried putting an EXIST subquery after FROM too but that didn't work either.

Is this possible? I'm probably missing something very obvious.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an ELSE in your CASE expression to combine the two "columns":

```
CASE
    WHEN T4.[U_DestType] = '6'
        THEN (SELECT
          'Company Limited' AS [ShipToCode]
          )
    ELSE T2.[ShipToCode]
END AS [ShipToCode],
```

And by the way, you didn't need to use a Sub-Select.   This would work just as well and is easier to read:

```
CASE
    WHEN T4.[U_DestType] = '6' THEN 'Company Limited'
    ELSE T2.[ShipToCode]
END AS [ShipToCode],
```

Comment: I'm a dummy, it all seems so obvious now. Thanks again.